# Harddisk partition not detected

Tags: partitioning, external-hdd

I have this Transcend storage device which I've had for 2 years now, but rarely use at all. After a couple of months, when I connect it to my computer again, it’s not being detected by the file manager at all. I check that it’s shown in `/dev`, but only `sdc` is showing, without any partition as shown in the image link shared:

[image: fdisk failed]

Can anyone help guide me what to do?

Comment: Is it a spinning disk or an SSD?

Comment: Open Disks app and see what it says.

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l` to list all drivees.